# When do I use fabs and when is it sufficient to use std::abs?

Tags: c++, math.h, cmath

I assume that `abs` and `fabs` are behaving different when using `math.h`. But when I use just `cmath` and `std::abs`, do I have to use `std::fabs` or `fabs`? Or isn't this defined?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

In C++, it's always sufficient to use `std::abs`; it's overloaded for all the numerical types.

In C, `abs` only works on integers, and you need `fabs` for floating point values. These are available in C++ (along with all of the C library), but there's no need to use them.

Comment: Is this on every platform the case? Esp. Windows and Mac OS X? Or is it at least in the C++ standard?

Comment: @brubelsabs: yes. There is no need for a separate fabs function in C++ since C++ has function overloading (abs can be defined for numerous types and it is in C++). It is also guaranteed by the standard. Of course if you dig around find some outdated compiler over 10 years old, you might find one that doesn't support it.

Comment: It's in the C++ Standard, so it's the case on every platform with a decent compiler, including Windows and Mac OS X. Clause 26.5 says that, in addition to the `int` version from the C library, there are overloads for `long`, `float`, `double` and `long double`. Clause 26.2.7 also defines an overload for `complex`.

Comment: If you  forget the `std::` and just use `abs`, your code will work as expected on windows but will use the `int` version on linux, which can be incredibly hard to debug.

Comment: "*all* the numerical types" [citation needed]. I can see int, long, long long, std::intmax_t, float, double, long double. No short or char versions (or unsigned versions) that I can see.

Answer (score 25):

It's still okay to use `fabs` for `double` and `float` arguments. I prefer this because it ensures that if I accidentally strip the `std::` off the `abs`, that the behavior remains the same for floating point inputs.

I just spent 10 minutes debugging this very problem, due to my own mistake of using `abs` instead of `std::abs`. I assumed that the `using namespace std;`would infer `std::abs` but it did not, and instead was using the C version.

Anyway, I believe it's good to use `fabs` instead of `abs` for floating-point inputs as a way of documenting your intention clearly.

Comment: That's weird. Your call should've been ambiguous (and thus an error) right?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using fabsf for float? So I don't think they are identical.

Comment: Beware of Android NDK g++, it also cedes to c abs() function instead of std::abs(). In Visual Studio c++ compiler however abs always points to std::abs() though.

Comment: @Nick, I think I agree with you: I don't seem to get that behaviour of Alan Turing i.e. for me the overloaded `std::abs` always seems to be invoked (and not the C-version of `abs`) when calling `abs` as long as `using namespace std;` is explicated at the beginning. I don't know if this is compiler specific though.

Comment: @Nick is not an error as there is a function name that matches. It is implementation defined which one will be chosen.

Answer (score 13):

There is one more reason to recommend `std::fabs` for floating-point inputs explicitly.

If you forget to include <cmath>, your `std::abs(my_float_num)` can be `std::abs(int)` instead of `std::abs(float)`. It's hard to notice.

Answer (score 1):

"abs" and "fabs" are only identical for C++ float types, when they can be translated without ambiguous overload messages.

I'm using g++ (g++-7).
Together with template usage and especially when using mpreal there are cases with hard "ambiguous overload" messages - `abs(static_cast<T>(x))` isn't always solving that.
When abs is ambiguous, there are chances that fabs is working as expected. For sqrt I found no such simple escape.

Since weeks I'm hard struggling on C++ "not existing problems". I'm updating an old C++ program to C++14 for more and better template usage than possible before. Often the same template parameter may be actual any standard float or complex type or a class type. Why ever, long double acted somewhat more sensible than other types.
All was working, and I had included mpreal before.
Then I was setting my default float type to mpreal and got a deluge of syntax errors.
That gave thousands of ambiguous overloads e.g. for abs and sqrt, crying for different solutions. Some were needing overloaded help functions, but outside of a template. Had to replace individually a thousand usages of 0.0L and 1.0L with the exact constant type using Zero or One or a type_cast - automatic conversion definition impossible because of ambiguities.

Up to May I found the existing of implicit conversions very nice.
But much simpler it would be without any, and to have typesave constants with safe explicit type_casts to any other standard constant type.