# Abs and using namespace std

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, absolute-value

Say I am using `using namespace std` (undeniably [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) and that I use the `abs` function in my code (to get [the overloaded absolute function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118165/when-do-i-use-fabs-and-when-is-it-sufficient-to-use-stdabs)). To be specific my MWE is:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 double f(-0.4);
 std::cout<<"abs(f) = "<<abs(f)<<std::endl;

}
```

If I comment out the `using namespace std;` line then the output is

```
abs(f) = 0
```

else the output is

```
abs(f) = 0.4
```

What I don't understand is how the "correct" abs function is invoked in the latter case given that even stdlib.h has an `abs` function that returns only `int`'s.

In fact the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118165/when-do-i-use-fabs-and-when-is-it-sufficient-to-use-stdabs) says that using `using namespace std;` may **not be enough**. Is this true? My MWE seems to contradict this.

I am on Linux and using gcc-4.8, which is arguably the most problematic combination to resolve dependencies.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works for me, with gcc 6.2.1

Comment: Your program works fine for me as well. It must be a compiler issue.

Comment: Updated to include compiler version gcc-4.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use

```
using namespace std;
```

you bring the following overloads of `abs` into scope:

```
std::abs(int)
std::abs(float)
std::abs(std::complex)
```

The call `abs(f)` resolves to `std::abs(float)`.

If you don't use

```
using namespace std;
```

there is only one `abs` function that you are able to use.

```
abs(int)
```

Hence, the call `abs(f)` resolves to `abs(int)`.

You can still remove the `using namespace std;` line and use `std::abs(f)` instead of just `abs(f)`.

Comment: Makes sense, I was mostly wondering if there was any scenario in which, despite having `using namespace std;` in the file, the `abs(int)` call was invoked whilst simply specifying `abs`.

Comment: @MaviPranav, since you accepted the answer, I am assuming you got the answers you needed. If not, let me know.

Comment: The answer is correct, but it's still not definitive to me whether a counterexample situation can exist i.e. `abs(int)` being invoked from a call to `abs`, despite `using namespace std;` being used.

Comment: Absolutely, abs(int) could be called if the #include <cmath> were removed (even with using namespace std).  This type of silent change when a header is removed is deadly in a larger application.  Fortunately, virtually all compilers will give a warning about truncation of a double value to an integer.  Yet one more reason to pay attention to compiler warnings.